# Python URLencode issue

Tags: python, urlencode

I am trying to modify an ANKI addon .py file that to be able to parse words from oxford

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
qs = urlencode({"q": "come along"})

URL = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/search/english/?{}"

print(URL.format(qs))
```

my output

"https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/search/english/?q=come+along"

but actually output should be like this

"https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-along?q=come+along"

how can I overcome this issue I am rather beginner

```
#-- coding:utf-8 --
import random
from ..base import *

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint



@register(u'Oxford_Article')
class Oxford_Article(WebService):

    def init(self):
        super(Oxford_Article, self).init()

    def _get_from_api(self):
        sleep(randint(1,3))
        
        param = {"q": "come along"}
        qs = urlencode(param)
        param['q'] = param['q'].replace(' ', '-')
        URL = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/{}?{}"
        
        data = self.get_response(URL.format(param['q'],qs))
        soup = parse_html(data)
        result = {
            'Article': u'',
        }

        # Article
        element = soup.find('div', id='entryContent')
        for s in element.select('script'):
            s.extract()
        if element:
            result['Article'] = u''.join(str(e) for e in element.contents)


        return self.cache_this(result)

    @export([u'entryContent', u'Article definition'])
    def fld_definate(self):
        return self._get_field('Article')
```

Comment: Just edit your URL. Remove the last `/` and change `search` to `definition`.

Comment: so now I got that link
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/englishq=come+along It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
param = {"q": "come along"}
qs = urlencode(param)
param['q'] = param['q'].replace(' ', '-')
URL = "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/{}?{}"
print(URL.format(param['q'],qs))
```

Comment: thank you so much it is working but it is not working on this I updated my thread

Comment: bro, I am not python developer I all I am doing, I open my notepad++ and modify related file I am doing that to able to modify my ANKI programme addon

Answer (score 2):

if you're getting error while parsing the data

just replace this code

```
data = self.get_response(URL.format(param['q'],qs))
soup = parse_html(data)
```

with this code

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(URL.format(param['q'],qs))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

also don't forget to import this

```
import urllib.request
```

Comment: I don't use any IDE to doing that just modifying file using with notepad++ thank for your effort. Appreciate it